# Mactex + Texstudio Mojave new installation: Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 〖 (U+3016)

Tags: texstudio, unicode, input-encodings, mactex, macos

It's been a while since my last time using Mactex + Texstudio, which worked fine back then. Now with fresh installation I'm getting the below error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 〖 (U+3016)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end{align}
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 〗 (U+3017)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end{align}
```

I've tried to:

1. Define the settings for UTF-8

Well this was not enough

2. ```
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3016}{\{}
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3017}{\}}
   ```

Which worked.

But I don't understand why I was getting this error, 
the specific file that was pointed by the error hold nearly the same "align" block:

No error block:

```
\begin{align}\label{eq:unixy} \nonumber
F_z(z)&=\mathbb{P}(\max(x,y)\leq z)\\
&=\mathbb{P}[(x\leq z,x>y)\cup(y\leq z,x\leq y)] \nonumber\\
&=\mathbb{P}[(x\leq z,x>y)+(y\leq z),x\leq y]
\end{align}
```

Error block:

```
\begin{align}\label{eq:minCDF}
F_Z (z)&=\mathbb{P}(\min(x,y)\le z)=\mathbb{P}(-\max(-x,-y)\le z)\nonumber\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\max〖(-x,-y)\geq -z〗 )\nonumber\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(\max(-x,-y)\leq-z)\nonumber\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(-x\le-z)\mathbb{P}(-y\le-z)
\end{align}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please provide a full minimal example instead of sniplets like this where we have to guess a lot in order to test your code.

Comment: See there! `&=\mathbb{P}(\max〖(-x,-y)\geq -z〗 )\nonumber`. `〖` and `〗` are there! That is why you gets the error.

Comment: Oh I missed it! thought the error message point to the "\end{align}" thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With older releases of LaTeX you'd get no output at all from the two Unicode characters, but a series of warnings

```
Missing character: There is no <E3> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <80> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <96> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <E3> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <80> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <97> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <E3> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <80> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <96> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <E3> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <80> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <97> in font cmr10!
```

Starting from TeX Live 2018, you'd get the error, because UTF-8 has become the default input encoding.

The `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` way is what you need.

I'd also use `split`, in this case.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3016}{\{}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3017}{\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:minCDF}
\begin{split}
F_Z (z)&=\mathbb{P}(\min(x,y)\le z)=\mathbb{P}(-\max(-x,-y)\le z)\\ 
&=\mathbb{P}(\max〖(-x,-y)\geq -z〗 )\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(\max(-x,-y)\leq-z)\\ 
&=1-\mathbb{P}(-x\le-z)\mathbb{P}(-y\le-z)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, if you don't want output from the two characters, use

```latex
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3016}{}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3017}{}
```